# send data to mdDatepicker of Angular Material with patchvalue

Tags: node.js, angular

in my fullstack proyect i need update de date in a formulary, for this, i use a formulary for recieve data from data base and set the inputs with the original value from the database. the problem is when i try to set the input of mdDatepicker i dont know what i do wrong.  this is the error

**Error: Datepicker: value not recognized as a date object by DateAdapter.**

backend: nodejs
database: mysql
front: angular 4

class

```
export class Empresa {
    constructor(
        public NUM_ID_EMPRESA: number,
        public STR_IDENTIFICACION: number,
        public STR_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION: number,
        public STR_NOMBRE: string,
        public createdAt: string
    ) {}
}
```

this are the controls for edit the formulary

```
 createControlsEdit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({       
      NUM_ID_EMPRESA: '',
      STR_NOMBRE:  ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      STR_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      STR_IDENTIFICACION: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(validaNum)])],
      createdAt: '' // this is the control for date
    })
  }
```

this is my patchvalue for the formulary

```
this.service.getEmpresa(id)
        .subscribe(
            rs => this.empresa = rs,
            er => console.log('Error:', er),
            () => {
            if (this.empresa.length > 0) {                   
                this.esEdicion = true;                    
                this.form.patchValue({                   
                NUM_ID_EMPRESA: this.empresa[0].NUM_ID_EMPRESA,
                STR_NOMBRE: this.empresa[0].STR_NOMBRE,
                STR_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION: this.empresa[0].STR_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION,
                STR_IDENTIFICACION: this.empresa[0].STR_IDENTIFICACION,
                createdAt: this.empresa[0].createdAt // here recieve data from model
              })
            }
          }
        )
  }
```

and this is my html view for mdDatePicker

```
<div class="form-group">
     <md-form-field>
         <input id="createdAt" formControlName="createdAt" mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" (click)="picker.open()" placeholder="Elija una fecha">
          <md-datepicker-toggle  mdPrefix [for]="picker" ></md-datepicker-toggle>
          <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
      </md-form-field>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key you use to refer to the date formControl in the patchValue call has an additional 'd' `createdAtd:` instead of `createdAt:`. Is that the issue?

**EDIT**

With reference to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6773#issuecomment-326569553) reported, it is likely due to the datepicker being assigned a string value instead of a real Date object. You can assign the initial value of the date control to `null` instead of `''` (may be this doesn't really matter, not sure though), then whenever you set a new value to that control, always make sure it is a real Date object (either using javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) library or using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

So in your example, you could try making these changes,

```
createControlsEdit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({       
      NUM_ID_EMPRESA: '',
      STR_NOMBRE:  ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      STR_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      STR_IDENTIFICACION: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(validaNum)])],
      createdAt: null // this is the control for date (setting to null)
    })
  }

this.service.getEmpresa(id)
        .subscribe(
            rs => this.empresa = rs,
            er => console.log('Error:', er),
            () => {
            if (this.empresa.length > 0) {                   
                this.esEdicion = true;

                // assuming your date format is 'yyyy-mm-dd', if different change this logic
                const str = this.empresa[0].createdAt.split('-');
                const dateObj = new Date(+str[0], +str[1] - 1, +str[2]); // doing 'month - 1' as it is zero-based   

                this.form.patchValue({                   
                NUM_ID_EMPRESA: this.empresa[0].NUM_ID_EMPRESA,
                STR_NOMBRE: this.empresa[0].STR_NOMBRE,
                STR_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION: this.empresa[0].STR_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION,
                STR_IDENTIFICACION: this.empresa[0].STR_IDENTIFICACION,
                createdAt: dateObj // use the Date obj created above
              })
            }
          }
        )
  }
```

You will likely have to make sure whenever you update this value later in your app, to be of a valid Date type instead of just a string. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but this not the issue, sorry, I already corrected the question

Comment: Okay. What is the value in `this.empresa[0].createdAt` ?

Comment: the value corresponds to a record of date type that is in the database, this is a value searched by a service through an id, and must be obtained by the form to later edit by datePicker and save it again

Comment: I know it is being used by the datepicker. But can you give an example of its value?

Comment: @Andy Updated my answer